# C++ Block Type is Valid error while deleting a pointer using destrcutor

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class String
{
private:
    int len;
    char *str;

public:
    String() {}

    String(const char *string):len(strlen(string))
    {
        str = new char[len + 1];
        strcpy(str, string);
    }

    String& operator=(const String& st)
    {
        len = st.len;
        str = new char[len];
        strcpy(str, st.str);
        return *this;
    }

    String operator+(const String& obj)
    {
        char *temp = new char[len + obj.len + 1];
        strcpy(temp, str);
        strcat(temp, obj.str);
        String copy(temp);
        delete[]temp;
        return copy;
    }

    ~String()
    {
        delete[] str;
    }
};

void main()
{
    String str1 = "Hel";
    String str2 = "low";
    String str3 = str1 + str2;
}
```

I am trying to delete the pointer in String class, using destructor.

But I see the message of Block Type Is Valid.

Can you tell me why?

And, I am so sorry for bad alignment, this is my first time to ask in stackoverflow

Comment: Does it say block type is **valid** or **invalid**? In any case, you need to follow the Rule of Three.

Comment: _"And, I am so sorry for bad alignment ..."_ Just use spaces, no tabs.

Comment: It says, block type is valid

Comment: `main` have to return `int`, and you've several  
occasions where you forget to `delete` some allocated memory.

Comment: You need to declare a copy constructor, currently your `return` statement in `operator+` causes a default copy, which copies the pointer, this causes you to try to use the value of a pointer after it has been deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see at least one bug in your code that is going to result in undefined behavior. I am not familiar with the actual compiler diagnostic you're asking about, but undefined behavior is undefined behavior. Who knows.

The bug is that the assignment operator is allocating too short of a buffer. As a result, this code is going to stomp on the heap.

The assignment operator should be doing:

```
str = new char[len+1];
```

Your constructor sets `len` to the size of the string that does not include the terminating null byte. Subsequently, the assignment operator will allocate one fewer bytes, for the assigned string. Compare the `new` in the constructor, with the `new` in the assignment operator.

The assignment operator is also leaking memory by not freeing the existing buffer, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: I think the reason is that str3 doesn't operate its constructor, and it just executes operator+. As a result delete[]str in ~string() of str3 sends the error to the user

Comment: An object will always execute its constructor, when it get instantiated. There are no exceptions to this rule.